# Excel SUM Conditional

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

I'm trying to complete a moderately complicated SUM function in Excel but am having no luck.

See the attached image for visual explanation.

[image: Excel]

> The objective is to take the sum of E, F, and G columns in only
>       the rows that meet the criteria. The criteria is that the sum 
>       of A and B columns must be greater than zero and the sum
>       of C and D columns must be less than zero. The sum of E+F+G is
>       the difference between A+B and C+D
>
> `IF(AND(SUM(A2:B2)>0,SUM(C2:D2)<0),SUM(E2:G2),0)` is the formula 
>       I use in each row of the I column. I want to consolidate all rows
>       into one formula because I will probably have close to 100 rows that
>       need to compute to 1 cell. An easy alternative would be to keep my
>       placeholder column (I) but it is not an option in my case. I have tried
>       combinations of `SUM`, `SUMIF`, and `SUMIFS` but am having a hard time.

I tried `SUMIF` because the [sum_range] parameter should've let me do what I want but every time it either read zero of #VALUE. I readup on the issue and it seems a workaround exists using arrays. I tried implementing the array as suggested by Microsoft but I always get a value of zero. I really don't want to have to use a macro for this. It seems so simple but after 5 hours of no progress I've learned otherwise. Any ideas?

[Microsoft Support Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260415/sumif,-countif-and-countblank-functions-return-value-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9+B2:B9>0)*(C2:C9+D2:D9<0)*E2:G9)
```

Comment: Simple, yet brilliant. You're my hero.